# Java: JButton that creates JTextField everytime it is pressed

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

Hy everyone,

I was just learning some new things with Java GUI, and I got stuck with a problem. This is what it looks like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2fNi.png]

I want a button that adds the data from the second JPanel in to the first one.But not only once. I want it to go to the first JPanel, everytime it is pressed.

So, the button should create a new JTextField in the first JPanel, below their respective categories "name" and "age" everytime it is pressed. It means that I have to modify the "Y" field everytime, so all the new JTextFields created by the button "add data" dont get pilled up.

I don't know how to make the button "add data" Works, the other things, I know how to do. I know how to make the button creates a JTextField, with the data I want to store, only once (using getText() and setText() ), but not how to create new JTetFields with diferente "y" field everytime it is pressed.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you click on the button to add people you should not display a new JPanel. Instead you should display a modal `JDialog`. A JDialog is just like a frame but generally is only displayed for a specific function and then closed.
2. On this dialog you will probably want two buttons: 1) Save Data and 2) Close. This will allow you to enter information for multiple people before closing the dialog.
3. To display the "person" information you should probably be using a `JTable`. A table allows you to display data in a row/column format. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for basic information to get you stated. Note, in this cause you will want to use a `DefaultTableModel` for your table and then you can just use the `addRow(...)` method to save the "person" information.
4. When you create the class for the dialog to get the "person" information you will want to pass the `DefaultTableModel` to this class as a parameter. Then when you click the "Save Data" button you get the information from the two text fields and update the TableModel. The table will be updated automatically.

So your first step is to create the main frame with the JTable with the two columns. Then you create a simple "Add Person" button. This button will then  add hard coded data to the table each time it is clicked by using the addRow(...) method. Once you get this working then you change the logic of the button to display the dialog and then you can enter the "person" information on the dialog and save it.